# pymongo $set on array of subdocuments

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a pymongo collection in the form of:

```
{
    "_id" : "R_123456789",
    "supplier_ids" : [
        {
                "id" : "S_987654321",
                "file_version" : ISODate("2016-03-15T00:00:00Z"),
                "latest" : false
        },
        {
                "id" : "S_101010101",
                "file_version" : ISODate("2016-03-29T00:00:00Z"),
                "latest" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

when I get new supplier data, if the supplier ID has changed, I want to capture that by setting latest on the previous 'latest' to False and the $push the new record.

$set is not working as I am trying to employ it (commented code after 'else'):

```
import pymongo
from dateutil.parser import parse

new_id = 'S_323232323'
new_date = parse('20160331')

with pymongo.MongoClient() as client:
    db = client.transactions
    collection_ids = db.ids

    try:
        collection_ids.insert_one({"_id": "R_123456789",
                                   "supplier_ids": ({"id": "S_987654321",
                                                     "file_version": parse('20160315'),
                                                     "latest": False},
                                                    {"id": "S_101010101",
                                                     "file_version": parse('20160329'),
                                                     "latest": True})})
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        print('record already exists')

    record = collection_ids.find_one({'_id':'R_123456789'})

    for supplier_id in record['supplier_ids']:
        print(supplier_id)
        if supplier_id['latest']:
            print(supplier_id['id'], 'is the latest')

            if supplier_id['id'] == new_id:
                print(new_id, ' is already the latest version')
            else:
                # print('setting', supplier_id['id'], 'latest flag to False')
                # <<< THIS FAILS >>>
                # collection_ids.update_one({'_id':record['_id']},
                #                           {'$set':{'supplier_ids.latest':False}})
                print('appending', new_id)
                data_to_append = {"id" : new_id,
                                  "file_version": new_date,
                                  "latest": True}
                collection_ids.update_one({'_id':record['_id']},
                                          {'$push':{'supplier_ids':data_to_append}})
```

any and all help is much appreciated.

This whole process seems unnaturally verbose - should I be using a more streamlined approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with positional operators.

```
collection_ids.update_one(
    {'_id':record['_id'], "supplier_ids.latest": true},
    {'$set':{'supplier_ids.$.latest': false}}
)
```

This query will update `supplier_ids.latest = false`, if it's true in document and matches other conditions.

The catch is you have to include field array as part of condition too.

For more information see [Update](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update)